# Nativescript build to device

Tags: nativescript

Whenever I try to build to a device I'm getting this error:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 "binding.node has
>   conflicting provisioning settings."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=binding.node has conflicting
>   provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=binding.node is
>   automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the
>   "signingCertificate" entry from your Export Options property list, or
>   switch to manual signing by setting "signingStyle" to "Manual.}

I can build to a simulator just fine. What would this be?

My .xconfig:

```
// You can add custom settings here
// for example you can uncomment the following line to force 
distribution code signing
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution
// To build for device with XCode 8 you need to specify your 
development team.
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <xxxxxxxx>;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've already answered in [the Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4369#issuecomment-464644586), most probably you have a dev dependency which cannot be signed in the dependencies list of your package.json and you need to follow the steps described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512390/nativescript-5-1-and-tns-modules-folder-in-ios-build/54512538#54512538) in order to resolve it.